# Excel Formula - Partial Match and show value

Tags: excel, match, formula, countif

I have been trying with COUNTIF, LOOKUP and MATCH and cannot seem to work out this formula and would really appreciate the help !

There is a list of POSTCODES (Column A) in Sheet 1 with a list of PARTIAL POSTCODES (Column A) in Sheet 2, with accompanying codes - CODE 1 (Column B) and CODE 2 (Column C).  What i am looking for is a formula that will :

1. Take the POSTCODE from Sheet 1
2. Lookup and do a partial match in POSTCODE in Sheet 2
3. If match then take CODE 1 and CODE 2 from Sheet 2 and enter it in Sheet 1

Example of what i am looking for : http://www.theukwebspace.co.uk/example.png

Comment: What do you mean by "partial match"? some examples would be helpful

Comment: I have created an example and linked it to http://www.theukwebspace.co.uk/example.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for excel formulas to do this for you?

How about:

```
=VLOOKUP((LEFT(A1, 5)), Sheet2!A:C, 2, FALSE)
```

In column B of Sheet1. A1 references the first column in sheet one, and you would change the 2 to a 3 in column C.

Comment: Thanks but if you look at the example i am looking for a lookup then to bring across to codes from reference sheet, SHEET2.

Comment: Do all the partial codes look like the ones in your example, a first set of characters, followed by a space then the first number of the next set of characters?

Comment: VLOOKUP looks good to me, that will bring you a value back from sheet2....but I see in your example there might be 5 or 6 characters, so assuming you want the match on everything up to the space + next character I would change to this version in B3: `=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3,FIND(" ",A3)+1), Sheet2!A:C, 2, FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(Sheet2!$A1;Sheet1!$A1));Sheet2!B1)
```

Paste this in B1 then fill the rest of the cells with it.